# phpstorm MySQL-Dialect string building with php

Tags: php, mysql, phpstorm

In my project I am using MySQL and therefore configured PhpStorm to use MySQL dialect for the query inspection.
I have an MySQL query that is built with normal SQL and also using PHP variables.

Let's assume I have the following code

```
$headline = 'Berlin';
$additional = (rand(1,5) > 2) ? ' AND t.public = 1' : '';
$query = "SELECT * FROM tours t WHERE t.headline = '". $headline . "'" . $additional .";";
```

If I print the query, it can look like this

```
SELECT * FROM tours t WHERE t.headline = 'Berlin' AND t.public = 1;
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM tours t WHERE t.headline = 'Berlin';
```

Both queries are correct. However, PhpStorm shows an error at the following part

```
>'"< . $additional .";";
```

with the message

> FOR, GROUP, HAVING, INTO, LIMIT, LOCK, ORDER, PROCEDURE or UNION expected, got '$('

The problem only occurs when I have a query element in a phpvariable. How would I solve this problem?

Comment: try add one **space character** in this line: `$query = "SELECT * FROM tours t WHERE t.headline = '". $headline . "'**space**" . $additional .";";`

Comment: Hi Alex. Unfortunetely this doesn't work on my Phpstorm (most recent verison). If I put a space there Phpstorm shows me an error at the semicolon at the end. If I remove the semicolon at the end it shows me the error at the position where I put the space again

Comment: What!? how space could break anything? may be you placed space in a wrong place?

Answer (score 2):

There is a great chance that PHPStorm raises you this error because SQL inspection is not powerful enough to perform analysis with variable expansion.

It's probably not a bug, just the inspector not capable of doing a complete SQL analysis with PHP variables injected on queries.

Comment: Hm, okay. That sucks. Do you know if I can ignore a single inspection error? So, I don't want to ignore SQL Inspection completely, just for one query

Comment: For one query I'm not sure. Hit Alt+Enter on a character concerned by the error, then hit right arrow to show inspection options. These options really depends on the context, so I'm not sure of what will be available for you.

Comment: One easy way to bypass that for a particular query is to separate the SELECT keyword from the query. For example:

$query = "SELECT" . " * FROM tours t WHERE t.headline = '". $headline . "'" . $additional .";";